# Bring nested value to top level in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to reshape a MongoDB document as followed:
This is how it looks at the moment:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a96d4a0af792cca1ec7d8cb"),
"Test" : "ABC",
"DATE" : "2018-02-28T16:04:55.00+01:00",
"Header" : "212735699",
"TraceIds" : [ 
    {
        "Id" : 1,
        "Names" : [ 
            {
                "LangCode" : "de",
                "CountryCode" : "DE",
                "Text" : "Komponente"
            }, 
            {
                "LangCode" : "en",
                "CountryCode" : "US",
                "Text" : "Component"
            }, 


        ],
        "Values" : [ 
            {
                "AId" : 1,
                "Names" : [ 
                    {
                        "LangCode" : "de",
                        "CountryCode" : "DE",
                        "Text" : "Teil"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "LangCode" : "en",
                        "CountryCode" : "US",
                        "Text" : "Part"
                    }, 

                ],
                "Value" : "1263000118"
            }, 

        ]
    }
],
```

Now I want to bring up the Value 1263000118 and give it the german name "Teil". All the other embedded values should vanish. So it should look like this:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5a96d4a0af792cca1ec7d8cb"),
"Test" : "ABC",
"DATE" : "2018-02-28T16:04:55.00+01:00",
"Header" : "212735699",
"Teil" : "1263000118",}
```

Would be great if someone could help me out here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregation framework :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        _id: your_id,
        // Treatment to select which nested value you want
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: "$_id",
        Test: "$Test",
        DATE: "$DATE",
        Header: "$Header",
        Teil: "$Values.$.Value
    }}
]);
```

Something like this should work